# Moving bitmap is not smooth and is jerky

Tags: java, android, eclipse

My update method for continuous updating.

```
@Override
public void update(float deltaTime) {
    Graphics g = game.getGraphics();
    List<TouchEvent> touchEvents = game.getInput().getTouchEvents();
    game.getInput().getKeyEvents();

    redPin.moveX(deltaTime);

    int len = touchEvents.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        TouchEvent event = touchEvents.get(i);
        if (event.type == TouchEvent.TOUCH_UP) {
            if (inBounds(event, 0, 360, 800, 120)) {
                if (gameOver) {
                    // TODO game over methods
                } else {
                    // TODO game is not over methods
                    level++;
                    blackBacking.randomizeX();
                    blackBacking.setWidth(level + 1);
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My bitmap class

```
public class RedPin {
    private int xTracker = 400;
    private int x = 400;
    private int y = 85;
    private int height = 111;
    private long speed = 1000;
    private float deltaTime;
    private int direction = 1;

    protected int getX() {
        if (xTracker <= 86) {
            x = -10;
        } else if (xTracker >= 714) {
            x = -10;
        } else if (xTracker <= 713 && xTracker >= 87) {
            x = xTracker;
        }
        return this.x;
    }

    protected int getY() {
        if (this.xTracker == 86 || this.xTracker == 714) {
            this.y = 88;
        } else if (this.xTracker == 87 || this.xTracker == 713) {
            this.y = 87;
        } else if (this.xTracker == 88 || this.xTracker == 89 || this.xTracker == 712 || this.xTracker == 711) {
            this.y = 86;
        } else {
            this.y = 85;
        }
        return this.y;
    }

    protected int getHeight() {
        if (this.xTracker == 86 || this.xTracker == 714) {
            this.height = 104;
        } else if (this.xTracker == 87 || this.xTracker == 713) {
            this.height = 105;
        } else if (this.xTracker == 88 || this.xTracker == 712) {
            this.height = 106;
        } else if (this.xTracker == 89 || this.xTracker == 711) {
            this.height = 107;
        } else if (this.xTracker == 90 || this.xTracker == 710) {
            this.height = 109;
        } else if (this.xTracker == 91 || this.xTracker == 709) {
            this.height = 110;
        } else {
            this.height = 111;
        }
        return this.height;
    }

    protected void moveX() {
        if (this.xTracker >= 734) {
            direction = 1;
        } else if (this.xTracker <= 66) {
            direction = -1;
        }
        xTracker = (int) direction * ((xTracker + 1)*deltaTime);
        x = (int) direction * ((x + 1)*deltaTime);
    }

}
```

g.drawPixmap(Assets.gameRedPin, redPin.getX(), redPin.getY(), 0, 0, 2, redPin.getHeight());

When i run the code with only x+1*deltaTime, there is a slight bit of jerkish movement.
when i set it to x+2 or anything higher the jerking movement is even greater. Is there any 
way i can make the movement smoother?

Comment: I think you're working too hard.  [Lerp](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/LinearInterpolator.html) seems to do most of what you're trying to accomplish here.

Answer (score 0):

Can you log the values of deltaTime? It may be because the refresh rate is too low (i.e. 20 FPS), or that there's a great variation for the deltaTime value, both would cause jerkiness. Also, if you test your code on an emulator, it'll definitely be jerky.

Comment: even running on a physical device, but with a debugger attached, can cause performance issues

Comment: i'm running on Nexus S. I read somewhere that i need to include interpolation?

Comment: Interpolation probably wouldn't help make your animations smoother, if you can post what kind of deltaTime's are passed there and post here, it maybe understand the source of the problem.

Comment: correction, the movement is not jerky actually if i only set it to +1. Is there anyway i can speed up the movement without adding more to the number of pixels it moves per an update?

Comment: Not sure if you are still looking for an answer, but another very possible cause is that it looks like you don't have sub-pixel precision to your objects.